# Netsuite: handling customers with subsidiaries?

Tags: parent-child, netsuite

OOTB, does Netsuite handle customers with subsidiaries? i.e., "parent-child" relationships?

For example, I need to keep SuperConglomerate as one Customer, as well as all of its 100 subsidiaries, and even potentially a handful of those subsidiaries have their own subsidiaries.

Or does that have to be a customization, to have subsidiary customers reference a parent company/customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, NetSuite supports Parent/Child relationships for customers out of the box.

From the NetSuite help documentation for creating customers:

> *If this is a child record of another record, select the existing parent record in the Parent Company field.*

We have many customers with parent/child relationships without using customizations.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I expected it would, but working with a group who mentioned this was not supported... and, not being a NS expert, I figured I'd check, given some of the platforms on the market that require 'customizations' for very basic things... Not sure what the specific issue actually is, but I guess it's out of my realm of concern. (Until integration time.)